# Emacs-AUCTeX-Okular

Tags: 11.10, emacs, latex, okular

I have Tex live 2011 installed with Emacs 23. AUCTeX and Okular. I have also configured Emacs/AUCTeX to work with Okular supporting forward and inverse search.

But. Here's my question. If I have Emacs and Okular docked side by side and when I click on Okular, the cursor is taken to Emacs. But. If I have Okular and Emacs in two maximized windows, and when I click Okular, the Emacs window is not brought up to the front.

Have I configured SyncTeX correctly or is this how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem today on Ubuntu 12.04. The main problem is that the Emacs window is not brought to front.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Emacs/AucTex/Okular/TexLive 2011. I found that if I press Shift+LeftMouse twice in Okular, the Emacs window will be brought front. So this can be seen as a workaround.

You could also configure the Custom Text-Editor in Okular.

First install xdotool

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then save the following script

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +$1 $2

fs=$2
filename=$(basename "$fs")
pathname=$(dirname "$fs")
xdotool search --name $filename windowactivate
```

The script will first call emacsclient, then bring a window whose title contains the filename of the TeX source to front.

Make the script executable and write the following command (don't include ~ in your path) in the Custom Text-Editor in Okular.

```
<absolute-path-to-script> %l %f
```

Hope it works.