# Kile doesn’t brings Okular to front

Tags: kile, okular

As @user49890 in [Emacs-AUCTeX-Okular](https://askubuntu.com/q/111578/54477) I got an equal problem with Kile and Okular. In configured both for SyncTeX and it works fine when Okular is closed and Kile quickbuilds the PDF, then Okular is opened in front of Kile. But if Okular is already opened with the window behind Kile’s window it stys hidden when Kile says `[ForwardPDF] test.pdf (okular)`

Is this a bug or did I made a wrong setting (I’m using the predefined configurations of Okular and Kile, though).

**Edit**
The problem remains wether I use Okular’s `--unique` option or not. And Using `ViewPDF` instead of `ForwardPDF` makes no difference too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a pretty similar setup, and I experience the same thing. 
It could be related to one or more of the current bugs with unity and window order/focusing/etc (which also affect me), e.g.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/864233

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/781931

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/compiz/+bug/772612

At least that's what I put it down to until now...

Comment: Thanks. Then it is an Ubuntu Problem and not Kile/Okular-Related right?

Comment: I guess so but I'm not totally sure. I've been using Okular only for a short time (months), and it's always been that way.